# Можно ли ссылку поставить вовнутрь label?

Tags: html, html5, вёрстка, label

Можно ли вот так поставить ссылку вовнутрь `label`? Валидацию такой код проходит. С одной стороны при нажатии на ссылку не происходит клика по чекбоксу, но в тоже время это один кликабельный элемент внутри другого. Это возможно? Или будет семантически не правильно? И почему? Везде ли такой код будет работать?

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container red">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
          <span class="custom-control-description">текст<a href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg">ссылка</a></span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если разместить ссылку в `label` то она не будет работать. Так же и на оборот. По-моему

Comment: @yuri добавила ссылку на изображение - работает, чекбокс тоже работает

Comment: Я знаю, но по логике, при клике на ссылке должен кликаться и `checkbox`, но он не нажимается при этом :)

Comment: А зачем так делать вообще? Семантически - ссылка это переход куда-то, лейбл - подпись к чекбоксу...

Comment: Ссылки в label работают отлично. Валидатор html горит зеленым ;)

Comment: @yuri да, но это работает, хотелось бы знать наверняка на что может повлиять такой код

Comment: @yozhezhi в моем случае это самый простой способ соответствовать макету, чтобы не городить Position:absolute например. Здесь приведен упрощенный вариант, чтобы показать суть. И во время поиска решений возник вопрос - можно ли так делать вообще? так как прямых запретов я не видела, и конструкция работает. Интересно узнать мнения людей, может кто-то сталкивался с какими-то проблемами в такой конструкции.

Comment: @visman да, валидатор не ругается, но меня честно говоря это удивило. Я бы поняла, почему\если бы он ругался, но почему он не ругается не могу понять...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Элемент anchor может употребляться внутри элемента label, как в HTML 4.01, так и в HTML5. Такая конструкция абсолютно валидна.
2. Наиболее удобным для пользователя способом применения будет следующий.

Поскольку **одному чекбоксу могут соответствовать несколько элементов label**, оптимально располагать ссылку (ссылки) между этими элементами.
Благодаря этому при нажатии по тексту внутри любого из label чекбокс отмечается, при нажатии на ссылку - не отмечается и никак не изменяет состояния.

```
<input id="cb" type="checkbox">
<label for="cb">I agree to the</label>
<a href="#" target="_blank">terms</a>
<label for="cb">and would like to continue</label>
```

Опять-таки, для удобства пользователя желательно давать ссылке атрибут target="_blank"; впрочем, это уже выходит за рамки вопроса.

Итак, ответ на последний вопрос вопроса будет таким: **такой код будет работать везде**.

Answer (score 7):

У валидатора нет проблем с этим кодом, значит стандарт позволяет. Если боитесь, что не во всех браузерах работает одинаково — проверьте и исправьте нежелательное поведение. Если текущее поведение не устраивает (чекбокс не нажимается при клике на ссылку) — исправьте при помощи JS. Итого: если вам нужно вставить ссылку в лейбл — вставляйте!

P.S. если задумали, чтобы ссылка из лейбла открывалась в этой же вкладке браузера, то не забудьте сохранять данные заполненной формы, в противном случае конверсия формы начнет стремиться к нулю, а под кем-нибудь обязательно прогорит стул.

Comment: А вдруг в валидаторе просто баг?)

Comment: между нами говоря, кому вообще какое дело что там в валидаторе )

Answer (score 5):

Можно, но тот человек, что нажмёт на ссылку (желая отметить чекбокс), проклянёт вас.

Comment: Визуально ссылка не находится в поле чекбокса, здесь упрощенная верстка для того чтобы передать суть.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/148001)

Comment: @cheops, да ну?